# why trait method needs asInstanceOf and class method don't

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I have defined the following trait:

```
trait Felem[T <: Felem[T]] {                                               
  def mul(that: T): T
  def square: T = this.mul(this.asInstanceOf[T])                            
}
```

I also define a class based on this trait:

```
class F2elem(val coef: Boolean) extends Felem[F2elem] {
  override def square: F2elem = this.mul(this)
  ...
}
```

My questions are about the need of "asInstanceOf" in the definition of the "square" method in the trait. If I remove it, I get the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Felem.this.type (with underlying type Felem[T])
required: T
def square: T = this.mul(this)
```

1. Why is it needed in the trait ?
2. Why it is not needed in the class ?
3. Does it cost anything in term of execution time or memory ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter of mult must be of type `T`.

When calling `mul(this)`, the this parameter is of type `Felem[T]`, which is not and does not conform to `T`. There is the additional constraint that `T` conforms to `Felem[T]`. But this is not what you want, you would need the opposite, `Felem[T]` to conform to `T`.

On the other hand, in `F2elem`, `T` is exactly `F2elem`, so it typechecks (completley unrelated to one being a trait and the other one a class)

Here is example to show that the definition in `Felem` must indeed not typecheck, and that it is possible to have implementors where `Felem[T]` does not conform to `T`.

```
class F3elem extends Felem[F2elem] // this is 2, not 3
```

This declaration is correct, `F2elem` which is given for `T` satisfies `T <: Felem[T]`. 
However, an inherited t`his.mul(this)` in `square` would be invalid, mult expect a `T`, that is `F2elem`, and this is `F3elem`. And they are unrelated.

What you probably want is that every `Felem` must be like `F2elem`, that is that `T` must be the type of the actual class. You can enforce this with a self type.

```
trait Felem [T <: Felem[T]] { this: T => /* your code */ }
```

When you write that, you state that in every implementation, the type of the implementation must conform to `T`. Doing that, it will typecheck, and you will not be allowed to instanciate F3elem above :

> error: illegal inheritance;  self-type F3elem does not conform to
>   Felem[F2elem]'s selftype F2elem
>          class F3elem extends Felem[F2elem] {

Answer (score 2):

1) In your `trait` `this` is not an instance of `T`:

```
scala> trait Felem[T <: Felem[T]] {
     |   def mul(that: T): T = that
     |   def square: T = this.mul(this.asInstanceOf[T])
     | }
defined trait Felem

scala> class F2elem extends Felem[F2elem]
defined class F2elem

scala> class F3elem extends Felem[F2elem]
defined class F3elem

scala> new F3elem()
res1: F3elem = F3elem@2e0b08f1

scala> res1.square
java.lang.ClassCastException: F3elem cannot be cast to F2elem
```

2) In your `class` `this` is `F2elem` and `T` == `F2elem`, so `this` is `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `T` as your method's parameter type. This means that whatever the type of `T` is will be the type that's required in the method (hence not needing the cast in the class, since its type is what is signified by `T` originally).

If you change the type of `that` to `Felem[T]`, you will not need the cast.